# Are real intervals open in the product topology RxR?

Tags: general-topology

Intervals are clearly open in $\mathbb{R}$. Are intervals open in the product topology $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ ? 
I need to know if $\varnothing \times O$ is open in $X^2$ if $O$ is open in $X$.

Comment: $\varnothing\times O=\varnothing$ for any set $O$

Comment: Choose any point in the unit interval in the product . Can you draw a product ball contained in the interval?